# OCI CLI command failing with Parse error when using --output table

Tags: jq, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I was trying a simple OCI CLI command when ran without the option --output table is working absolutely fine, but when i add that option -- output table it is giving parse error.
Please let me know if i miss anything here..

### Working command

```
 oci --profile $PROF bastion session list --all --bastion-id $BSTN_OCID  |jq -r '.data[].id'
```

### Failing command

```
 oci --profile $PROF bastion session list --all --bastion-id $BSTN_OCID --output table |jq -r '.data[].id'
```

### Error

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

Comment: Going by image search, it looks like `--output table` produces an ASCII table. Why would you expect `jq` to be able to process something that is ostensibly *not* JSON?

Comment: ok got it. I was able to do it using --query

Answer (score 1):

As updated by Botje - JQ can not process as its not JSON. I used --query and it worked.

```
oci bastion session list  --bastion-id  $BSTN_OCID --output table --profile $PROF --all --query 'data[].id'
```